# Looping through the result set

Tags: powershell

When I run this command:

```
$k = Get-Process | select Name -First 3
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Name
----
AESTSr64
ApplicationFrameHost
BtwRSupportService
```

I want to place each result in a separate variable of type string and get its length. I want to know how can I access individual rows returned.

I tried a foreach as follows:

```
foreach ($k in $three) {
  write $k
}
```

to get

```
Name
----
AESTSr64
ApplicationFrameHost
BtwRSupportService
```

I want to output only the result without the headers and the dashes and show the length of each string on the same line (when I convert the input using `.ToString()` I get empty string and zero length because each result is treated as an object).

I tried this, but it produced the wrong lengths:

```
foreach ($k in $three) {
  $t = $k | Out-String
  write ("{0} {1}", $t, $t.Length)
}
```

So how can I produce something like this:

```
AESTSr64                   08
ApplicationFrameHost       20
BtwRSupportService         18
```

**Edit**

One way to get the desired result, using the answer and notes below:

```
$three = Get-Process | select -First 3 | ForEach-Object Name
foreach ($k in $three) {
  [string]$c = "{0,-15} {1}" -f $k, $k.Length
  Write-Host $c
}
```

Comment: `$k` -> `$k.Name`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Excellent comment, I changed to [string]$t=$k.Name and that fixed the length. Thanks.

Comment: `[string]` is unnecessary, `$k.Name` is already of type `string` :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do it simply :)

```
   get-process | select Name, @{Name="NameLength";expression={$_.Name.length}} -first 3
```

if you want loop on result:

```
 $list=get-process | select Name, @{Name="NameLength";expression={$_.Name.length}} -first 3

 foreach ($item in $list)
 {
     write-host ("{0} {1}" -f $item.Name, $item.NameLength)
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I was wondering if you have any reference where I could read on the @{...}, does that denote a formatted string?

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I am still learning this stuff...and about 10 other things...!

Comment: your welcome ;)   PowerShell is a good and util script langage. have a good day

Answer (score 2):

> I want to place each result in a separate variable of type
>   string and get its length. I want to know how can I access individual
>   rows returned.

You can store the result in a variable, but typically it won't have type string, it will be an array of Process objects.  If you really want strings you could do this:

```
$p = get-process | select -first 3 | ForEach-Object name
```

But `$p` *is still an array*, so it's length will be 3!  You can get the length first value as `$p[0].length`...   Or you can break out the individual values like this:

```
$p1, $p2, $p3 = get-process | select -first 3 | ForEach-Object name
```

But note that with this last example, if more than 3 objects were to be returned, then `p3` would be an array of all but the first two...

Comment: Try my second example..., that does a better job of doing what you asked for.